# How do I read only x number of bytes of the body using Net::HTTP?

Tags: ruby, http

It seems like the methods of Ruby's Net::HTTP are all or nothing when it comes to reading the body of a web page. How can I read, say, the just the first 100 bytes of the body?

I am trying to read from a content server that returns a short error message in the body of the response if the file requested isn't available. I need to read enough of the body to determine whether the file is there. The files are huge, so I don't want to get the whole body just to check if the file is available.

Answer (score 13):

This is an old thread, but the question of how to read only a portion of a file via HTTP in Ruby is still a mostly unanswered one according to my research. Here's a solution I came up with by monkey-patching Net::HTTP a bit:

```
require 'net/http'

# provide access to the actual socket
class Net::HTTPResponse
  attr_reader :socket
end

uri = URI("http://www.example.com/path/to/file")
begin
  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    # calling request with a block prevents body from being read
    http.request(request) do |response|
      # do whatever limited reading you want to do with the socket
      x = response.socket.read(100);
      # be sure to call finish before exiting the block
      http.finish
    end
  end
rescue IOError
  # ignore
end
```

The rescue catches the IOError that's thrown when you call HTTP.finish prematurely.

FYI, the socket within the `HTTPResponse` object isn't a true `IO` object (it's an internal class called `BufferedIO`), but it's pretty easy to monkey-patch that, too, to mimic the `IO` methods you need. For example, another library I was using (exifr) needed the `readchar` method, which was easy to add:

```
class Net::BufferedIO
  def readchar
    read(1)[0].ord
  end
end
```

Comment: Beware that the response might be compressed, and then one would get 100 "binary" octets in the example above. When expecting text, use `request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, {'Accept-Encoding' => 'entity'})` to disable compression. And note that if the response is chunked, [one will first get a line with the chunk size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding#Format), in hex. So, `response.socket.read(100)` will yield a line with the hexadecimal number `64`, and another line with 100 octets (or multiple lines with smaller sizes, if the server sends smaller chunks).

Answer (score 12):

Shouldn't you just use an HTTP `HEAD` request (Ruby `Net::HTTP::Head` method) to see if the resource is there, and only proceed if you get a 2xx or 3xx response? This presumes your server is configured to return a 4xx error code if the document is not available. I would argue this was the correct solution.

An alternative is to request the HTTP head and look at the `content-length` header value in the result: if your server is correctly configured, you should easily be able to tell the difference in length between a short message and a long document. Another alternative: set the `content-range` header field in the request (which again assumes that the server is behaving correctly WRT the HTTP spec).

I don't think that solving the problem in the client *after* you've sent the GET request is the way to go: by that time, the network has done the heavy lifting, and you won't really save any wasted resources.

Reference: [http header definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Comment: Tried that, The server sends an OK response and a 0 for content-length. This is the P4Web server from Perforce.

Comment: Hmm. If your vendor sends 200 OK when it really means is 404 not found then you should raise a priority bugrep with them!

Comment: Using `HEAD` is the correct way to go from the client side. If their server is broken they need to fix it. Unfortunately, that doesn't make the OPs task any easier though, because companies and vendors commonly don't care what someone using the content encounters when hacking their server.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do this once, and the only thing that I could think of is monkey patching the `Net::HTTP#read_body` and `Net::HTTP#read_body_0` methods to accept a length parameter, and then in the former just pass the length parameter to the `read_body_0` method, where you can read only as much as length bytes.

Comment: If you happen to still have code for that, I'd love to see it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have it handy, but it was quite simple, as I only needed to read these bytes, and I didn't care about the following bytes. So I added another parameter to #read_body with 'nil' default, and in #read_body_0 I added parameter len=nil and I had something along the lines of: if len ; @socket.read len, dest; return; end

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the content server only returns a short error page?

Doesn't it also set the `HTTPResponse` to something appropriate like 404. In which case you can trap the `HTTPClientError` derived exception (most likely `HTTPNotFound`) which is raised when accessing `Net::HTTP.value()`.

If you get an error then your file wasn't there if you get 200 the file is starting to download and you can close the connection.

Answer (score 2):

To read the body of an HTTP request in chunks, you'll need to use `Net::HTTPResponse#read_body` like this:

```
http.request_get('/large_resource') do |response|
  response.read_body do |segment|
    print segment
  end
end
```

Comment: Tried this. request_get still want to download the whole file before processing the block.

Comment: This works for me for chunked responses (with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`), if I also add a `break` in both blocks (before both `end`s) to stop after getting the first chunk. In that case using the block with `read_body` makes Ruby NOT read the full response (and not even wait for it). But, again: my response is chunked to start with, and those are small chunks. I doubt HTTP allows a client to explicitly request a chunked response, nor allow it to suggest a maximum chunk size; it seems the `Range` header should be used instead if the server does not return (small) chunks.

Answer (score -4):

You can't.  But why do you need to?  Surely if the page just says that the file isn't available then it won't be a huge page (i.e. by definition, the file won't be there)?

Comment: this isn't an answer. This is you failing to imagine how something could be necessary/useful/desirable because you personally haven't encountered it yet. Who cares why he needs to? Who cares if you have some end run around the question? The question is "How do I read only x number of bytes of the body using Net::HTTP?
". Do you know how? If not why are you wasting everyone's bandwidth?