# Read only portion of a remote file with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, io, streaming

I need to pull in the first X characters/bytes/whatever of a large remote XML file.

The code below successfully pulls down the file in chunks but I can't figure out how to cut it off after a certain size/amount of data.

```
    uri = "https://domain.com/file.xml"

    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
        http.set_debug_output $stderr

        http.request request do |response|
          StringIO.open do |str|
            response.read_body do |chunk|
                str.puts chunk
            end
          end
        end
    end
```

I've tried something like the below, but that creates a string with the contents of the first chunk repeated over and over.

```
response.read_body do |chunk|
    while str.size < 50000
     str.puts chunk
    end
  end
```

I've also tried:

```
response.read_body do |chunk|
   if str.size > 50000 
      puts "BIG ENOUGH!"
      break
   end
end
```

This also results in the result str to be the contents of the first chunk repeated over and over until it reaches the specified size limit.

Comment: is this only to know if the resource exists ?, if so, you should use `Head`(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82349/how-do-i-read-only-x-number-of-bytes-of-the-body-using-nethttp).

Comment: No. it is to pull a portion of the contents to preview In a web display

Comment: Do you intend that the XML be valid or do you only want to show its presence or content without it being usable?

Comment: If you want to stop after a certain point simply concatenate the incoming data to a buffer and check its size, or count loops and exit when you've reached a predefined limit. It's the same as if you were looping in any other situation and needed to bail at a given line or amount of read data. `break` might be of use.

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan.  The XML does not needs to be valid (Nokogiri seems to be able to handle it).  I've tried the looping based on size as show in my questions but I wind up with the same initial data chunk, but simply repeated over and over.  I'll update to show another attempt with the same results.

Comment: Nokogiri wants valid XML. Without that it resorts to trying to fix it up, similar to a browser, which can radically change the XML DOM. When you load and parse some XML, check the `errors` method for the returned parsed DOM and it'll show you what Nokogiri had to do if it found problems. If it doesn't return an empty array then you have to be ready for selectors to break.

Comment: One additional thing you can try is setting the [HTTP header `RANGE` value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). Of course that assumes the HTTPd recognizes that header.